# How to run a zip file on Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I downloaded a zip file but I don't know how to run it on Android studion. I tried File/New/Import Project/(chose the project) then press ok. Then I receive this message bar: "Cannot Import, The project file specified already exists." What does that mean and how can I run a zip file on Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the file and import the project.